# Determine whether doc is new or exists in mongoose Post middleware's 'save'?

Tags: mongoose

From [Mongoose JS](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) documentation:

```
schema.post('save', function (doc) {
  console.log('%s has been saved', doc._id);
})
```

Is there any way to determine whether this is the original save or the saving of an existing document (an update)?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

[@aheckmann reply at github](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/1474)

```
schema.pre('save', function (next) {
    this.wasNew = this.isNew;
    next();
});

schema.post('save', function () {
    if (this.wasNew) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

`isNew` is an key used by mongoose internally. Saving that value to the document's `wasNew` in the pre save hook allows the post save hook to know whether this was an existing document or a newly created one. Additionally, the `wasNew` is not commited to the document unless you specifically add it to the schema.

Comment: @jysperm your comment is confusing to me because the example uses both `wasNew` and `isNew`... so what has changed to what?

Comment: what changed `isNew` before it gets to the `Schema.post('save')` middleware?

Comment: It is recommended to use `this.$locals.isNew` instead of directly adding properties to the Mongoose object.

Answer (score 6):

Edit: see [Document#isNew](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-isNew) for information on Document#isNew

Comment: Mongoose is well-known for its awesome documentation.

Answer (score -12):

```
schema.post('save')
```

No longer recognizes update events. So might as well just do the following:

```
schema.post('save', function () {
    console.log('New object has been created.');
});
```

Comment: That's not true at all, this answer should be removed